# Pixel-Position of Cursor in UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextview

Is there a way of getting the position (CGPoint) of the cursor (blinking bar) in an UITextView (preferable relative to its content). I don’t mean the location as an NSRange. I need something around:

```
- (CGPoint)cursorPosition;
```

It should be a non-private API way.

Comment: Are you talking about the text insertion point? i.e the blinking vertical bar?

Comment: There isn't a public method to get that information. What are you trying to achieve? There might be another way.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's painful, but you can use the `UIStringDrawing` additions to `NSString` to do it. Here's the general algorithm I used:

```
CGPoint origin = textView.frame.origin;
NSString* head = [textView.text substringToIndex:textView.selectedRange.location];
CGSize initialSize = [head sizeWithFont:textView.font constrainedToSize:textView.contentSize];
NSUInteger startOfLine = [head length];
while (startOfLine > 0) {
    /*
     * 1. Adjust startOfLine to the beginning of the first word before startOfLine
     * 2. Check if drawing the substring of head up to startOfLine causes a reduction in height compared to initialSize.
     * 3. If so, then you've identified the start of the line containing the cursor, otherwise keep going.
     */
}
NSString* tail = [head substringFromIndex:startOfLine];
CGSize lineSize = [tail sizeWithFont:textView.font forWidth:textView.contentSize.width lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
CGPoint cursor = origin;
cursor.x += lineSize.width;
cursor.y += initialSize.height - lineSize.height;
return cursor;
}
```

I used `[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]` to find word boundaries.

This can also be done (presumably more efficiently) using `CTFrameSetter` in `CoreText`, but that is not available in iPhone OS 3.1.3, so if you're targeting the iPhone you will need to stick to `UIStringDrawing`.

Comment: It's a nice workaround I also played around with.

To find word boundaries I found it best to use CFStringTokenizer.

Your implementation doesn't give the x and y coordinates but rather the size of the chars in the line containing the caret until the caret, right?

However, I accept your approach as an answer since I eventually did something similar adopted to my needs.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer about CFStringTokenizer, I overlooked that. Subtracting lineSize.height from initialSize.height will give you the y offset of the cursor (relative to the UITextView) and the width of the final line fragment gives you the x offset.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on
/*
     * 1. Adjust startOfLine to the beginning of the first word before startOfLine
     * 2. Check if drawing the substring of head up to startOfLine causes a reduction in height compared to initialSize.
     * 3. If so, then you've identified the start of the line containing the cursor, otherwise keep going.
     */
I also require cursor position in UITextView.

Comment: @tek3: initialSize is the total rectangle containing the whole string, but it doesn't tell you what x-coordinate the cursor is at in the last line.  By chopping off words from the end and sizing the incrementally smaller string, you can find the index for the beginning of the last line.  Then, using that, you can find the width of the last line up to the cursor (lineSize).  (By the way, this is a really nice answer.)

Comment: I think, to be honest *tek3* just wants to know what code to put inside the `while` function.

Comment: @tony, i have implement ur algorithm, but when the keyboard appear in the 2nd time or higher, selectedRange.location always show 2147483647, it means that the location is not found. So, how can i found it location? in where method i have to implement or called this algorithm exatcly?? really need ur answer please...

Comment: @tony see my question, please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633379/pixel-position-of-cursor-in-uitextview

Answer (score 49):

**Requires iOS 5**

```
CGPoint cursorPosition = [textview caretRectForPosition:textview.selectedTextRange.start].origin;
```

Remember to check that `selectedTextRange` is not `nil` before calling this method. You should also use `selectedTextRange.empty` to check that it is the cursor position and not the beginning of a text range. So:

```
if (textview.selectedTextRange.empty) {
    // get cursor position and do stuff ...
}
```

Comment: This is iOS 5 only. Although -caretRectForPosition is available 3.2 and later, UITextView didn't conform to UITextInput until iOS 5

Answer (score 14):

**SWIFT 4** version:

```
if let cursorPosition = textView.selectedTextRange?.start {
    // cursorPosition is a UITextPosition object describing position in the text (text-wise description)

    let caretPositionRectangle: CGRect = textView.caretRect(for: cursorPosition)
    // now use either the whole rectangle, or its origin (caretPositionRectangle.origin)
}
```

`textView.selectedTextRange?.start` returns a text position of the cursor, and we then simply use `textView.caretRect(for:)` to get its pixel position in `textView`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes — as in there's a method to get the cursor position. Just use

```
CGRect caretRect = [textView rectContainingCaretSelection];
return caretRect.origin;
```

No — as in this method is private. There's no public API for this.

Comment: Exactly this method would be what I search, but I can't use private API of course. Other solution?

Comment: Doesn't seem to exist in iOS 4.2. I get a no such selector exception from my UITextView.

Answer (score 1):

> I try to mark a selected text, i.e. I receive a NSRange and want to draw a yellow rectangle behind that text. Is there another way?

I can advise you some trick:

```
NSRange selectedRange = myTextView.selectedRange;
[myTextView select:self];
UIMenuController* sharedMenu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
CGRect menuFrame = [sharedMenu menuFrame];
[sharedMenu setMenuVisible:NO];
myTextView.selectedRange = selectedRange
```

Using this code, you can know get the position of the cut/copy/past menu and there place your yellow rectangle.

I did not find a way to get the menu position witout forcing it to appear by a simulated select operation.

Regards
Assayag

Comment: I implemented this for testing and it's a nice hack but actually not useful since you can't conclude from menuFrame to the cursor position (problems when arrow is pointing down and not up etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Take a screenshot of the UITextView, then search the pixel data for colors that match the color of the cursor.

```
-(CGPoint)positionOfCursorForTextView:(UITextView)textView {
     //get CGImage from textView
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(textView.bounds.size);
     [textView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
     CGImageRef textImageRef = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext().CGImage;
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();  

     //get raw pixel data
     CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
     uint8_t * textBuffer = (uint8_t*)malloc(Width * Height * 4);
     NSUInteger bytesPerRow = 4 * Width;
     NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
     CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(textBuffer, Width, Height,
                                             bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                             kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);


     CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

     CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, Width, Height), textImageRef);
     CGContextRelease(context);

     //search 

     for(int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
     {
         for(int x = 0; x < Width * 4; x += 4)
         {
             int red   = textBuffer[y * 4 * (NSInteger)Width + x];
             int green = textBuffer[y * 4 * (NSInteger)Width + x + 1];    
             int blue  = textBuffer[y * 4 * (NSInteger)Width + x + 2];  
             int alpha   = textBuffer[y * 4 * (NSInteger)Width + x + 3];    


             if(COLOR IS CLOSE TO COLOR OF CURSOR)
             {
                 free(textBuffer);
                 CGImageRelease(textImageRef);
                 return CGPointMake(x/4, y);
             }
         }
     }

     free(textBuffer);
     CGImageRelease(textImageRef);
     return CGPointZero;
}
```

Comment: Yay for creative answer, nay for error prone and compute intensive.