# Cursor position in a UITextView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I am looking for a **non** private way to find the position of the Cursor or Caret (*blinking bar*) in a `UITextView` preferably as a `CGPoint`.

There may be a question like this already but it does not provide a definitive way for doing it.
And, 
**I do not mean the `NSRange` of the selected area.**

Comment: can you tell us why you want to do this for some more background info?

Comment: It's for displaying a `UIMenuController`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just got it in another thread:

Requires iOS 3.2 or later.

```
CGPoint cursorPosition = [textview caretRectForPosition:textview.selectedTextRange.start].origin;
```

Remember to check that selectedTextRange is not nil before calling this method. You should also use selectedTextRange.empty to check that it is the cursor position and not the beginning of a text range. So:

```
if (textview.selectedTextRange.empty) {
// get cursor position and do stuff ...
}
```

[Pixel-Position of Cursor in UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633379/pixel-position-of-cursor-in-uitextview)

Comment: +1 yep, this is on the [`<UITextInput>`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol

Comment: This is not implemented in iOS 4.3 or below, as one would think when reading the documentation. It only works in iOS5+

Answer (score 2):

SWIFT 2.1 version:

```
let cursorPosition = infoTextView.caretRectForPosition( (infoTextView.selectedTextRange?.start)! ).origin

print("cursorPosition:\(cursorPosition)")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such way. Full stop.

The only thing you could do to come *close* is to in parallel lay out the text using CoreText, there calcualte the text position from a point and apply that on the UITextView. This, however, works with non-0 selections only. In addition CoreText has a different text layout engine, that e.g. supports kerning, which UITextView doesn't. This may result in deviations of the rendered and laid out text and thus give sub-optimal results.

There is absolutely no way to position the caret. This task is even very though if you do use private API. It's just one of the many *"just don't"* in iOS.

Comment: So there's absolutely no way to calculate the position of the caret?

Comment: Nope. Not with UITextView. As I said: you can lay the text out a second time using CoreText and calculate the position there, but that gives you estimates at best.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4** version:

```
// lets be safe, thus if-let
if let selectedTextRange = textView.selectedTextRange {
    let caretPositionRect = textView.caretRect(for: selectedTextRange.start)
    let caretOrigin = caretPositionRect.origin
    print(">>>>> position rect: \(caretPositionRect), origin: \(caretOrigin)")
}
```

We simply use `textView.selectedTextRange` to get selected text range and than `textView.caretRect(for:)` to get `CGRect` defining position of the caret.