# Monotouch (C#) equivalent to rangeOfCharacterFromSet

Tags: c#, objective-c, ios, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to port some Objective-C code into C# - [Code can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920944/how-to-find-a-pixel-positon-of-a-cursor-in-uitextview) and it uses `NSString`'s `:rangeOfCharacterFromSet` more than once.

As far as I understand, `:rangeOfCharacterFromSet` returns a subset of the string based on what options you pass in. [Apple docs here will explain it better.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfCharacterFromSet:options:range:)

Is there a Monotouch binding that I'm missing? (I had a quick check of the rosetta and couldnt find it) Or is there an alternative C# approach I should be taking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is almost the same as String.IndexOfAny. rangeOfCharacterFromSet just returns the a range for the index of the first character it finds from your set of characters. String.IndexOfAny takes a character array and tells you the first index it finds for any of those characters.

Comment: Try this. 
string testString = "mynewstring";
testString.IndexOfAny(...);